# Update. LetsEncrypt certificates in two different docker containers

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, docker-volume

I have few containers, which supports HTTPS connections:

```
certbot:
  image: certbot/certbot
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  # Update certificates every 12 hours.
  entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

It mounts LetsEncrypt certificates and updates it every 12 hours.

Also, I have two additional containers:

```
nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    - ./nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:ro
    - frontend-webroot:/var/www/app.com/public_html/:ro
    - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  depends_on:
    - api
    - frontend
  # Reloads nginx every 6 hours to make it sure everything is OK.
  command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

Which mounts certificates and reloads nginx one per 6 hours (as it's recommended)

and another container:

```
api:
  container_name: api
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  ports:
    - "9002:9002"
  volumes:
     - /usr/src/app/app/static
     - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
     - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  depends_on:
    - postgres
```

This container provided REST API and I'm not sure, it's a great idea to reload this container every X hours to update LetsEncrypt certificates.

What is wrong in this architecture? And how it might be improved to avoid reloading of container with REST API, but to make it possible to work with certificates?

**UPDATE**

What I expect from my app:

There should be available as home pages, etc. as API calls like:

```
GET https://localhost:9000/api/endpoint  # API call
GET https://localhost:443/home  # Home page from another container with React app
```

etc.

Comment: What’s your SSL terminal point (looking at from the client end)? Is it the nginx ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly `SSL terminal point`, but yes, nginx handles my HTTP(s) requests.

Comment: OK, do you want communication between the nginx to your API container HTTPS as well?

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha, I've updated my original post